# Safari extension builder no "+" sign to add new extension folder

Tags: safari, safari-extensions, file-extensions

I have an extension that I need to build back to safariextz, but there is no + sign to add new extension. In the tutorials there are + signs but they are old tutorials and there is no new information. How do I build extension?

Comment: Can you add a link to the tutorial you're following? I feel like my answer is likely to just be reiterating what you're already reading, but the + still shows for me in the latest version of Safari and TP, or I'm thinking of a different +.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In Safari, from the Develop menu, choose Show Extension Builder.

   [image]
2. Choose Continue from the Xcode promotion sheet if shown.
3. From the bottom-left of the window, click the + button.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't click on "Build Package" to build the extension and save it on my desktop or anything. Only install..